# import fiona : ImportError: cannot import name 'calc_gdal_version_num'

Tags: python-3.x, gdal, geopandas, fiona

I'm trying to install geopandas.

Whether I do one of these :

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
# or
conda install -c conda-forge fiona
# or
pip3 install Fiona‑1.7.9‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl # downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona
```

When I try either `import geopandas` or `import fiona`, I get the following error :

```
  File "<ipython-input-229-c9ee6bd24dbc>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from geopandas.io.file import read_file

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 3, in <module>
    import fiona

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import (

ImportError: cannot import name 'calc_gdal_version_num'
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

(I'm on windows 7 64 bit by the way, in case it's relevant)

---

**EDIT :**

It seems this behavior happens only in the IPython console of Spyder (v3.1.4). It doesn't happen when using the python3 command line in the terminal, or the python console of Spyder. I would still love a fix for the IPython console of Spyder, the python console in Spyder is reaaaally slow.

Comment: Just had the exact same problem. Close and reopen current IPython console of Spyder did the trick for me just in case anyone else's facing the same issue.